# Getting 'Missing Lifetime specifier' error

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, lifetime

This is my code:

```
use std::ptr;

struct Query<T>{
  data: T,
  prev: & Query<T>,
  next: & Query<T>,
}
impl<T> Query<T>{
  fn new(name: T) -> Query<T>{
    Query{
      data: name,
      prev: ptr::null(),
      next: ptr::null(),
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting 'missing lifetime specifier' where I am referencing `&Query<T>`. How do I fix this error?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the Rust Book: http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html.  You're also confusing borrowed pointers and raw pointers, which isn't going to get you anywhere.  Finally, you appear to be trying to make a doubly linked list, which is *not* something you should be attempting before learning the basic semantics of the language: Rust is exceptionally unforgiving about this.

Comment: I am reading the book and am currently working with referencing the next and previous query object. Though, it seems I need pointers to do that because otherwise it will be accessing 'infinite' queries, as the book has stated I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that `&T`/`&mut T` and `*const T`/`*mut T` are different types of pointers in Rust. The former are called "references" and they are statically checked in various ways (including borrowing analysis) and they can't be null or point to some invalid object. The latter are called "raw pointers" and are used primarily in abstractions implementations and for FFI.

Consequently, writing

```rust
Query {
    data: name,
    prev: ptr::null(),
    next: ptr::null(),
}
```

when `prev` and `next` are of type `&Whatever` is incorrect - `ptr::null()` returns values of type `*const Whatever` which is not compatible (safely) with `&Whatever`.

References in Rust always have some lifetime associated with them - it is used by the compiler to check that references always point to valid pieces of data. This lifetime is specified in reference type: `&'a T`. In most cases the compiler can infer correct lifetimes automatically, so you seldom need to write them in types of local variables or even in function declarations:

```rust
let x: &str = "hello";

fn print_str(s: &str) { println!("{}", s); }
```

However, when you want to put references to a structure, there is just no way the compiler can infer the lifetime in the structure declaration (because it can be arbitrary and depends on the way the structure values 
are used), and so you need to specify lifetime parameters explicitly:

```rust
struct Query<'a, T> {
    data: T,
    prev: &'a Query<'a, T>,
    next: &'a Query<'a, T>,
}
```

In this particular case, though, it seems that you want to implement some kind of doubly linked structure. Unfortunately, Rust references can't be used for this. Lifetime requirements prohibit creation of loops via references - you just can't store a reference to `x` in `y` if `x` has a reference to `y` inside it. The only way such structure can be constructed is through mutation:

```rust
let mut x = SomeStructure(None);
let y = SomeStructure(Some(&x));
x.0 = Some(&y);
```

But you can't mutate an object which has a reference pointing to it, that is, the above code is invalid.

The thing you're trying to achieve is usually called [intrusive data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004162/what-does-it-mean-for-a-data-structure-to-be-intrusive), and for now they are not well supported in Rust. There is an [RFC issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/417) on that, and we may probably see some progress on them in future.

There are several things you can do here, the most easiest one probably would be to refactor your code in such a way that you won't need to use a doubly-linked structure. Almost always you can put your data in a contiguous array like `Vec` and use indices to access it, and most likely it would be more efficient even for simple traversal because of cache locality.

Another option would be to use a non-intrusive linked list, like the one which is available [in the standard library](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html).

And, of course, you can always drop to using raw pointers. There is nothing wrong in using them when they are required, and most of the standard library abstractions (like the linked list above) are using them in some way internally. In your case, however, they should be the last resort - most likely there are ways to do what you want without them.

Comment: Yeah, I was attempting to create a form of a database from scratch using this method, but apparently it isn't possible at the moment. I'll find some way to do it.