# Why is it better to use entire entry (e.g. tree node) type as container template parameter instead of stored data type?

Tags: c++, templates, tree, containers, nodes

Recently I've come across a C++ template class that implemented a red-black tree. I expected its template parameter to be the type to be stored in the tree:

```
struct MyData {
    // data to be stored
};

template <class T>
class RbTree {
    // implementation
};

// usage:
RbTree<MyData> treeInstance;
```

Instead, I found that it expected a node type with specific requirements:

```
struct MyDataNode {
    MyDataNode* rbe_left;
    MyDataNode* rbe_ight;
    char rbe_color;
    // data to be stored
};

template <class Entry>
class RbTree {
    // implementation
};

// usage:
RbTree<MyDataNode> treeInstance;
```

My question is: why would you want to implement a container this way? Does this/Can this have better performance as opposed to the 'standard' way (described above)?

Comment: The search term for this is "intrusive containers".

Comment: Check [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004162/what-does-it-mean-for-a-data-structure-to-be-intrusive)

Comment: Thanks for the search term and the other question!